# Weird issue fetching HTTP URL on Production AppEngine instance [Java]

Tags: google-app-engine

I am quite puzzled by this behavior.
I have a Java AppEngine instance which makes an http call to a "settings.php" on another server. But I get the following error:
ERROR :

```
java.io.IOException: Could not fetch URL: http://<3rdpartywebsite>/settings.php
    at com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceImpl.convertApplicationException(URLFetchServiceImpl.java:138)
    at com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceImpl.fetch(URLFetchServiceImpl.java:45)
    at com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceImpl.fetch(URLFetchServiceImpl.java:30)
```

...

I have tried using URLFetchService and even a simple HttpURLConnection class. Even tried with a different User-Agent and other http headers, but to no avail.

What is baffling is that the same code and website works fine on Local Eclipse Dev environment, works via Browser (can see php text) AND works on the Compute Engine too! Only the Production App Engine throws the "could not fetch" error. Unfortunately this is not a transient error, it fails 10/10 times.

Any idea what could be going wrong or something that I can try?

Thanks, Asim

Comment: Is this a well-known public service, that has per-IP rate limiting? What kind of response are you getting back?

Comment: Not so "well-known", but its public (no auth). The production server simply throws the IOException while curl, browser, compute engine and localhost work (200)

Comment: Did you try changing the user-agent header?

Comment: yes played around with different user-agents, but no luck

Comment: Well, `IOException` means that server just dropped the connection, without sending any reply. Why it's doing this for requests from production GAE is beyond me.